Excel VBA: Auto sort column when formula result changes
I'm trying to get VBA to auto sort a column in a Table in Excel when the formula result in the cells in the same column are changed/updated. However, the auto sort code shown below is not triggering unless I manually enter a value into the cell.
I tried this code but the auto sort does not happen when the formula result changes/updates. If I manually enter a number into the cell in the column then it does auto sort.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim SalesTable As ListObject
Dim SortCol As Range

Set SalesTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("APAC")
Set SortCol = Range("APAC[Product Value]")

If Not Intersect(Target, SortCol) Is Nothing Then
    With SalesTable.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=SortCol, Order:=xlDescending
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
End If

End Sub

Then I tried changing the event to the following but it didn't make a difference
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim SalesTable As ListObject
Dim SortCol As Range

Set SalesTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("APAC")
Set SortCol = Range("APAC[Product Value]")

If Not Intersect(Target, SortCol) Is Nothing Then
    With SalesTable.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=SortCol, Order:=xlDescending
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
End If

End Sub

I also tried doing this event but it also did not work:
Private Sub Worksheet_SheetCalculate(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim SalesTable As ListObject
Dim SortCol As Range

Set SalesTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("APAC")
Set SortCol = Range("APAC[Product Value]")

If Not Intersect(Target, SortCol) Is Nothing Then
    With SalesTable.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=SortCol, Order:=xlDescending
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
End If

End Sub

Any suggestions?
Many thanks in advance

Try debug your code by debug print the Target address? Then you can learn the behavior of each event under each kind of action you take first.
